# What does &**this return exactly?

Tags: c++, pointers

this is a pointer to the calling object (it returns the r-value).

*this is a pointer to the pointer of the calling object (it returns the value of the address).

**this is a pointer to the pointer of the pointer of the calling object (???).

&***this is a reference to the pointer of the pointer of the pointer of the calling object (???).

```
std::vector<int>:: iterator i = vector1.begin();
```

i is the pointer to its own r-value (returns its own value).

*i is the pointer of a r-value of an object contained in a vector (returns the value pointed in &value).

**i is the pointer to the pointer of a r-value of an object contained in a vector (???).

I am really confused.

Here's a sample code where we find the expression &**this:

```
class _Iter
{
private:
    ListElem *pCurr;
    const List *pList;

public:
    _Iter(ListElem *pCurr, const List *list)
        : pCurr_(pCurr), pList(list)
    {}

    T& operator*() { return pCurr_->data; }
    T* operator->() { return &**this; }
};
```

Comment: The caller gets `&pCurr->data`.

Comment: You have to remember that `*` works exactly backwards depending on whether it's in a declaration or an executable statement.

Comment: "this is a pointer to the calling object (it returns the r-value)" named variables can't be r-value

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`this` is a pointer to the current object.

`*this` is a reference to the current object, i.e. `this` dereferenced.

`**this` is the returned value of the overloaded unary `operator*` function called on the current object.

If the object returned from `**this` has an overloaded `operator&()` function, then `&**this` evaluates to the returned value of `(**this).operator&()`. Otherwise, `&**this` is the pointer to the returned value of the overloaded unary `operator*` function called on the current object.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
   int b;
   int a;
   int& operator*() {return a;}

   int* test()
   {
      return &**this;
   }
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   std::cout << "Address of a.a: " << a.test() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Address of a.a: " << &(*a) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Address of a.a: " << &(a.a) << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Address of a.a: 0x7fffbc200754
Address of a.a: 0x7fffbc200754
Address of a.a: 0x7fffbc200754
```

Comment: See if this is going to make it clearer (or more confusing):
`**this` can be interpreted as `this -> operator*()`.  Therefore `&**this` is `& (this->operator*())` which is taking the address of the returned value of overloaded `*` operator for current object  :P

Comment: `&**this` could be `operator&` called on the returned value of the unary `operator*` . In fact if the `operator*` returns a non-reference then it must be, as you cannot take the address of a temporary.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a class `Foo` and a method of this class that use `this` and the object `Foo obj` then

`this` - is a value of type `pointer to Foo` that has a value of address of object `obj`

so you can write like this (for example in Foo:test()):

```
Foo *addr = this;
```

so `addr`is a variable of type `pointer to Foo` that is initialized with a address value of object `obj` of class `Foo`.

All pointers in C++ can be dereferenced with `*`. So when you dereference a pointer to an object you get that object

```
Foo *addr = get_pointer_to(obj); //function that return a pointer to object

//three equivalent ways to call someMethod() of object obj of class Foo
obj.someMethod();
addr->someMethod();
(*addr).someMethod();
```

Upper part of code illustrates that object `obj` and dereferenced pointer `(*addr)` have the same syntax, because they are the same object.

C++ allows you to overload different language operators.  So when you write (**this) the compiler looks to `this` and find that `this` is type of pointer to `Foo`, so dereferencing `*this` gives object of type `Foo`. Then the compiler find `(* (*this))`. But `Foo` is not a type of the pointer, so by default there is no `*` operator. So the compiler will returen an error and break the compilation. But if you define(overload) `operator*()` in class `Foo` then the compiler will call this method. So `**this` is equivalent to `this->operator*()` or to `(*this).operator*()`.

The last one is `operator&()`. By default this operator returns a pointer to object. But of course it can be overloaded and return something else.
So `&**this` can return 
1) an address of object that was returned by `operator*()` applied to the object (*this)
2) return value of method `operator&()` of the object that was returned by `operator*()` which was applied to (*this).

If there is no `operator*()` defined then `&**this` won't compile.

In addition if there is no `operator*()` defined and no `operator&()` defined then the construction of `&**some_pointer` will either not compile or will return (*some_pointer). And I can guarantee that (*some_pointer) will be a pointer.